# HTML Redirect issue with Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, mod-proxy, ubuntu-8.04, html5

I am facing an issue with the ProxyPass on my Apache server on Ubuntu. I have configured Apache to deal with Virtual Hosts on my server. There is an application with runs on the server and uses ports 8001 8002. I need to do something like `www.example.com/demo/origin` to display the contents that I would see when I visit `www.example.com:8000`. The contents to be displayed are a host of HTML pages.

This is the section of the virtual host config that has issues

```
ProxyPass /demo/vader http://www.example.com:8001/  
ProxyPassReverse /demo/vader http://www.example:8001/  

ProxyPass /demo/skywalker http://www.example.com:8002/  
ProxyPassReverse /demo/skywalker http://www.example.com:8002/
```

Now when I visit `example.com/demo/skywalker`, I see the first page of port 8002, say the `login.html` page.

The second should have been `www.example.com/demo/skywalker/userAction.html`, instead the server shows `www.example.com:8000/login.html`. In the error logs I see something like:

```
[Mon Nov 11 18:01:20 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1850): proxy: HTTP: FILE NOT FOUND /htdocs/js/demo.72fbff3c9a97f15a4fff28e19b0de909.min.js
```

I do not have any folder htdocs in the system.

This is only an issue while viewing `.html` pages. Otherwise, no such issue occurs.

When I visit `localhost:8001` it will show any and all contents without any errors or issues.

`www.example.com/demo/skywalker` displays a separate webpage

`www.example.com/demo/origin` displays a different webpage

and

`www.example.com/demo/vader` displays a different webpage.

I have also tried to use one more type of combination,

```
<Location /demo/origin/>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
  ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:8000/ /
</Location>
```

This fails as well.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as Apache reeves prosing goes, do you have these settings in place as well?

```
# Proxy specific settings
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

The reason I ask is that the error is based on a JavaScript file not loading. And [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) will not allow JavaScript to load content from the same domain.  And `ProxyPreserveHost` would preserve `example.com` when making a request to `www.example.com:8001` or `www.example.com:8002`

**EDIT:** Going to attempt a more specific example. I suggest you redo your proxy logic & try this.

```
# Settings for adding a trailing slash to the URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(demo)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/ [R=301,L]

# Settings for Apache Reverse Proxying
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

  # Proxy specific settings
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /demo/vader http://www.example.com:8001/  
  ProxyPassReverse /demo/vader http://www.example:8001/  

  ProxyPass /demo/skywalker http://www.example.com:8002/  
  ProxyPassReverse /demo/skywalker http://www.example.com:8002/

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip. i now have that in my Virtual Host configuration.
however, now, when i visit https://www.example.com/demo/vader/, it takes me to 
   http://hello.example.com/login

Comment: hello.example.com is another virtual host that is currently ran on the same apache server.

Comment: i now can redirect my https://www.example.com/demo/origin/ to www.example.com:8001/login.html, however, the URL in the browser changes as well....is there a way in which i can keep the Browser URL to https://www.example.com/demo/origin/login.html and still make the server work?

Comment: this is what i added to my virtual host configuration

    `<Location /demo/origin/>
        ProxyPass http://www.example.com:8001/
        ProxyPassReverse /
    </Location>`

Comment: Added edits with a more specific example.